# VMWare Player Run as Service

Tags: windows, services, vmware-player

I have a VMWare Player running a VM at all times. However I want the server to run that Virtual Machine on boot (without logging in). This will allow me basically to restart the Server and when it loads to the login screen it's already running VMWare. Any ideas? I have tried reading up on it however websites suggest VMWare Server. This is no longer backed by VMWare anymore. So I am looking to either make VMWare Player a service or if anyone else has any other ideas?

Running Win 7 on my server btw

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Have you considered switching VM products (to another company)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out ESXi ([ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html)). I have a HP Desktop successfuly running it. You will have make sure you're hardware ([Check Here](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?action=base&deviceCategory=server)) is supported but it may end up solving your issue plus it also gives you an excuse to play around with a great product.:)

Comment: Not sure I have the right gear for this program. I will give it a go though no harm in trying.^^ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried ESXi and got it to work. It is really advanced and you need a lot of time and knowledge. After I was successful, I decided to throw everything away and run VMware player as a service. :)

It is possible using this very old free microsoft wrapper (google for explanations about srvany):
ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/winnt/winnt-public/reskit/nt40/i386/srvany_x86.exe

Or there are also commercial tools:
http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunVMwarePlayerAsAService.html

Or you can try switching to VirtualBox (.org), which can run in the background just from the command line.